# An IVP has at least two solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the IVP:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{|y(x)|}$$

$$y(x_0) = 0$$

Show that it has at least two solutions. I really don't know how to do this. I don't know of any necessary conditions for the uniqueness of the solution (if there are any).

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: In this case you don't need any necessary condition for the uniqueness of the solution. You have just to give two different function who satisfies your IVP.

Comment: One of the solutions is $y = 0$.. Can you find another?

Comment: @Mattos, can you?

Comment: @goldenratio Have you even tried?

Comment: $y = \frac{x^2}{4}$. Thanks guys.

Comment: @GitGud, when I posted the question no; because I didn't know what should I do.

Comment: What do I do now? Should I delete the question or something?

Comment: @goldenratio I meant it after your reply "Can you?" to Mattos'.

Comment: Another option is to answer it yourself completely, and mark it as best answer. That way, someone else might find the question, and might find it interesting.

Comment: @GitGud, it wasn't serious. The remark was too obvious that I doubted he knew what the other solution might be.

Comment: @goldenratio Well, I see it the otherwise. One usually solves the equation blindly to find $x\mapsto \frac{x^2}4$ and the constantly null solution might be forgotten. I could see myself saying the exact same thing as Mattos'.

Answer (score 2):

Define the functions $y_0$ and $y_1$ by
$y_0(x) = 0$ for every $x$, $y_1(x) = 0$ for every $x\le x_0$, and $y_1(x)=\frac14(x-x_0)^2$ for every $x>x_0$, then $y_0$ and $y_1$ are two different solutions of this IVP.